# Output of aggregate function to create a table

Tags: r, format, output, aggregate

I am using the function aggregate that to get several statistics at the same time:

```
temp<-aggregate(AUClast~RIC+STUD, nca_sim[!is.na(nca_sim$RIC),], 
      FUN= function(x) 
        c(N=length(x), 
          Mean=mean(x), 
          SD=sd(x),
          Median=median(x),
          Min=min(x),
          Max=max(x)
          ))
```

If I print the output, I see 8 columns (two row/ID names and 6 statistics). But aggregate output contains only 3 columns (two ID columns and all the statistics in one column).
So, when I want to assign name to each column, I get this error message:

```
colnames(temp) <-c("Renal Function", "Study", "N", "Mean", "SD", "Median", "Min", "Max")
Error in names(x) <- value : 
  'names' attribute [8] must be the same length as the vector [3]
```

So, how do I assign the 8 names to 8 columns?
Just for clarity, I need to do this so that I can pass it to "kable" to produce formatted table with my assigned column names.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution. The main point is that the last column is a matrix column, not several vectors, one per statistic computed in `aggregate`.

Note that the way to extract the results matrix is absolutely general, this column is always the last one and therefore it's column number is always `ncol(temp)`.

The following post is relevant: [Difference between `[` and `[[`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1169456/the-difference-between-bracket-and-double-bracket-for-accessing-the-el)

```r
# make up a test data set
df1 <- mtcars[c("mpg", "cyl", "am")]
# it's not strictly needed to coerce the 
# grouping columns to factor
df1$cyl <- factor(df1$cyl)
df1$am <- factor(df1$am)
names(df1) <- c("AUClast", "RIC", "STUD")

# exact same code as the question's
temp <- aggregate(AUClast ~ RIC + STUD, df1, 
                  FUN = function(x) 
                    c(N = length(x), 
                      Mean = mean(x), 
                      SD = sd(x),
                      Median = median(x),
                      Min = min(x),
                      Max = max(x)
                    ))
# see the result
temp
#>   RIC STUD  AUClast.N AUClast.Mean AUClast.SD AUClast.Median AUClast.Min
#> 1   4    0  3.0000000   22.9000000  1.4525839     22.8000000  21.5000000
#> 2   6    0  4.0000000   19.1250000  1.6317169     18.6500000  17.8000000
#> 3   8    0 12.0000000   15.0500000  2.7743959     15.2000000  10.4000000
#> 4   4    1  8.0000000   28.0750000  4.4838599     28.8500000  21.4000000
#> 5   6    1  3.0000000   20.5666667  0.7505553     21.0000000  19.7000000
#> 6   8    1  2.0000000   15.4000000  0.5656854     15.4000000  15.0000000
#>   AUClast.Max
#> 1  24.4000000
#> 2  21.4000000
#> 3  19.2000000
#> 4  33.9000000
#> 5  21.0000000
#> 6  15.8000000

# the error
colnames(temp) <-c("Renal Function", "Study", "N", "Mean", "SD", "Median", "Min", "Max")
#> Error in names(x) <- value: 'names' attribute [8] must be the same length as the vector [3]

# only three columns, the last one is a matrix
# this matrix is the output of the anonymous function
# aggregate applies to the data. 
str(temp)
#> 'data.frame':    6 obs. of  3 variables:
#>  $ RIC    : Factor w/ 3 levels "4","6","8": 1 2 3 1 2 3
#>  $ STUD   : Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 1 1 1 2 2 2
#>  $ AUClast: num [1:6, 1:6] 3 4 12 8 3 ...
#>   ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
#>   .. ..$ : NULL
#>   .. ..$ : chr [1:6] "N" "Mean" "SD" "Median" ...

# three columns
(nc <- ncol(temp))
#> [1] 3

# extract the 3rd column temp[[nc]], not the data.frame temp[nc]
# and bind it with the other columns. It is also important 
# to notice that the method called is cbind.data.frame,
# since temp[-nc] extracts a data.frame. See the link above.
temp <- cbind(temp[-nc], temp[[nc]])

# not needed anymore!
# colnames(temp) <-c("Renal Function", "Study", "N", "Mean", "SD", "Median", "Min", "Max")

temp
#>   RIC STUD  N     Mean        SD Median  Min  Max
#> 1   4    0  3 22.90000 1.4525839  22.80 21.5 24.4
#> 2   6    0  4 19.12500 1.6317169  18.65 17.8 21.4
#> 3   8    0 12 15.05000 2.7743959  15.20 10.4 19.2
#> 4   4    1  8 28.07500 4.4838599  28.85 21.4 33.9
#> 5   6    1  3 20.56667 0.7505553  21.00 19.7 21.0
#> 6   8    1  2 15.40000 0.5656854  15.40 15.0 15.8
```

<sup>Created on 2023-05-06 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

The assignment of new `colnames` is only needed to make the first two columns' names more descriptive, not to get rid of the `AUClast.` prefix.

Comment: Yes, many thanks.  Your code is better than similar solution I just implemented as below: `cuttemp1<-temp$AUClast
newtemp1<-cbind(temp, cuttemp1)
newtemp2<-select(newtemp, -3)
colnames(newtemp2) <-c("Renal Function", "Study", "N", "Mean", "SD", "Median", "Min", "Max")`